# Radiobuttonlist check is checked

Tags: jquery

How to check radiobuttonlist is selected or not using jQuery

```
if ($("#<%=rblMaritalStatus.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked").length < 0) {
    $(".error").text('Select at least one marital satus');
    $("#ConfirmationModal").modal('show');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Satpal OP wants to execute that block if length === 0.. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try bellow code it could help you

```
    if ($("#<%=rblMaritalStatus.ClientID %> input:radio").is(":checked")) {
$(".error").text('Select at least one marital satus');
$("#ConfirmationModal").modal('show');
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [use JQuery `is`,](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments. Since `input[type=radio]:checked` is single selection it nicely fits this purpose.

```
if ($("#<%=rblMaritalStatus.ClientID %>").is('input[type=radio]:checked')) {
    $(".error").text('Select at least one marital satus');
    $("#ConfirmationModal").modal('show');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: **Thank you** @LIUFA you are right i had just common mistake